# Multiple regression with constraints on coefficients

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, optimization

I am performing a returns analysis. The idea is to regress a time-series of returns on the returns of various asset classes. The beta coefficients must be constrained such that sum of the coefficients is 1 and no coefficient is less than 0 or greater than 1. These beta coefficients can then be interpreted as explaining what % of returns are explained by exposure to the various asset classes.

Are there any packages in R that let me setup the above regression and benefit from the attendant reporting on model fit statistics? Or do I need to do some homework on setting up constrained least squares optimization in R (please provide any references to recommended R packages)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the MGCV package to fit a constrained regression where the coefficients could not be negative:

[Constrained Regression](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/tianblog/2006/07/fitting-constrained-least-square.html)

Also the 'quadprog' package with the solve.QP function may be useful.

Both, however, have a little bit of a learning curve, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConsReg package.

cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConsReg/index.html

It's very easy to use