# Solving linear regression with weights and constraints

Tags: r, regression

I would like to solve a linear regression (in R) with weights $w$ and a constraint.

In other words, I would like to find $x$ that minimizes the sum of squares
$$\sum_i w_i(b_i-Ax_i)^2$$

On top of that I have an external vector $d$, which I would like to use in a constraint, such that $d \cdot x \le 5$.

Is this something that would be possible to do in R with `solve.QP` or perhaps some other R script?

**Edit**: I am adding a bounty for a solution that doesn't require any other custom software except the cran packages. While rstan works perfectly unfortunately I am unable to install it on my production servers due to old versions of some libraries.

Comment: Note that the weights are not a complication at all, because they can be absorbed in the values of $b$ and $A$, leading to an ordinary least squares problem with a single linear constraint. That means you problem is solved as described at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24193 .

Comment: Very nearly the same question is asked--and answered in four different ways--at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61733. It differs only in explicitly addressing the two dimensional case.

Comment: @user777 I am sorry about that: I was thinking that if these threads were close enough, we could merge your answer with the ones there.  I liked your explicit demonstration of `rstan`, which has no parallel in the answers within the other threads.

Comment: @user777 I liked your solution as it was addressing this specific problem. If possible can you add it back? If anything it should be informative to someone else.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I was looking at other threads as well. The four different ways address a problem of a slope within the borders, not the sum of coefficients. The first link was helpful but I am still struggling to wrap my head around solve.QP or mgcv. I was hoping my question is generic enough to be useful for others and also sufficiently different from existing solutions in other threads.

Comment: There is no essential mathematical difference between bounding the slope and bounding the sum of coefficients: both are bounds on linear combinations of the coefficients. The solutions offered to those questions apply with very little change to your slightly more general formulation, thereby immediately giving you access to a variety of approaches to choose from. However, I have not voted to close your question, because although it does appear to be answered elsewhere, evidently it does take a little mathematical manipulation to see that those answers can apply.

Comment: @whuber I think I've finally cracked it, but since this is the first time I've ever attempted to solve a problem like this, I'd appreciate your expert feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the mgcv package. With the toy data we used before, it works just fine. (I'm uncertain why `rstan` is so confident in its results... I'm still looking into it.)

```
set.seed(1880)

N       <- 1500
d       <- c(1/2, 2/pi, 2/3)
x       <- c(2, 1, 3)
limit   <- 5
d%*%x <= limit

A       <- cbind(1, rnorm(N), rnorm(N))
b.hat   <- A%*%x
wgt     <- rexp(N)
b       <- rnorm(N, mean=b.hat, sd=wgt)

library(mgcv)

pin <- c(1.5, .75, 2.5)
Ain <- matrix(d, nrow=1)

M   <- list(y=b, w=wgt, X=A, p=pin, Ain=-Ain, bin=-limit, C=matrix(1, ncol=0, nrow=0))
pcls(M)

1.8844996 0.9421333 2.9770852
```

The inequality in this package is flipped the other direction by default. So we have to multiply both sides by $-1$.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, thank you very much @user777! It works flawlessly on my data. I will award bounty tomorrow, as 24h need to pass. Time for me to read "Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R" to keep up with your expertise. Hope you don't mind I selected this as a accepted answer instead of rstan. Rstan code is very useful nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really glad that this solves your problem. As for expertise, I follow CV daily, and it's always an education in how much I have yet to learn. On the other hand, I'm probably punching above the weight class for BA's in political science... ;)

Comment: As for rstan, there's honestly little reason to use it; I just wanted to see if I could (and the answer is somewhat mixed!).

Comment: I noticed a funny thing. On my data, if I set the same seed as in the above example I do get a correct solution. Otherwise my solution does not seem to converge and instead I am getting values very close to zero.

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you're supplying a good starting point?

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I have a complicated model to fit, I usually just fit it directly in `rstan` because it's great at fitting highly constrained coefficients, and because it's easy to include penalties and transformations of variables. This is true even when I'm not explicitly fitting a Bayesian model.

This is what I've worked up for your particular problem.

```
library(rstan)

set.seed(1880)

N       <- 1500
d       <- c(1/2, 2/pi, 2/3)
x       <- c(2, 1, 3)
limit   <- 5
d%*%x <= limit
> TRUE
A       <- cbind(1, rnorm(N), rnorm(N))
b.hat   <- A%*%x
tau     <- 5
wgt     <- rexp(N)
Sigma   <- tau*wgt
b       <- rnorm(N, mean=b.hat, sd=Sigma)

constrained.reg <- "
    data{
        int<lower=1>        N;
        int<lower=1>        K;
        vector<lower=0>[N]  wgt;
        matrix[N,K]         A;
        vector[N]       b;
        vector[K]       d;
        real            limit; // s.t. d*x<=limit
    }
parameters{
    real<upper=limit>   c; // this is the largest possible value of x%*%d.
    simplex[K]      sim_x;
    real<lower=0>       tau;
}
transformed parameters {
    vector[K]   x;
    vector[N]   b_hat;
    vector[N]   Sigma;

    x       <- d .*sim_x /c;
    b_hat   <- A*x;
    Sigma   <- tau*wgt;
}
    model{
        b ~ normal(b_hat, Sigma);
        increment_log_prob(-2*log(tau)); // uniform prior on beta, noninformative prior on tau
    }
    generated quantities{
        vector[N]   resid;
        resid   <- (b_hat-b) ./Sigma;
    }
"
fake.data   <- list(N=N, A=A, K=3, b=b, wgt=wgt, d=d, limit=limit)

fit.test    <- stan(model_code=constrained.reg, data=fake.data, iter=10)

system.time(fit     <- stan(fit=fit.test, iter=1000, data=fake.data))
print(fit, c("x", "tau")); x
```

I realized that I was being dense and that we can enforce the inequality by sampling a value *as large as* the maximum permissible dot product result and then transforming appropriately.

```
     mean se_mean   sd 2.5%  25%  50%  75% 97.5% n_eff Rhat
x[1] 1.99       0 0.01 1.98 1.98 1.99 1.99  2.00  1645 1.00
x[2] 0.99       0 0.01 0.97 0.98 0.99 0.99  1.00   624 1.00
x[3] 3.00       0 0.01 2.98 2.99 3.00 3.01  3.02   945 1.00
tau  4.82       0 0.09 4.62 4.76 4.82 4.88  5.00   558 1.01
```

These results look fine to me.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks @user777! I wonder how difficult it would be to do the same with one of the methods @whuber suggested.

Comment: When you have a jackhammer, everything looks like a sidewalk.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what @ssdecontrol is referring to :-), but as far as the other answers go, one (as I recall) suggested finding the weighted least squares solution. If it does not satisfy the constraint, then find the *equality*-constrained solution. Observe that (1) this requires only two least squares calculations, so it is efficient and fast and (2) in either case you obtain a covariance matrix for the estimates. Continuing in the analogical vein, that would make this problem about as easy as breaking a saltine into your soup, so you can put away the jackhammer :-).

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure I fully understand. What happens when neither solutions meets the constraints?

Comment: The second one, if it exists, is guaranteed to meet the constraints, by construction. Otherwise, there is no solution.  (But there always will be when the weights are positive.) Here's an example: fit a line $y=ax+b$ to $(x,y)$ data with the constraint $a+b\le 5$. If the OLS estimates do not satisfy that constraint, now fit the model $y=ax+5-a$ to those data. (You could easily do that by fitting the no-intercept model $y-5=a(x-1)$ to the data $(x-1,y-5)$, for instance.) I hope it's obvious the constraint will be met and that no special software is needed.

Comment: With the expanded explanation, your meaning is, indeed, obvious. The great thing about CV is that I literally never stop learning.

Comment: @whuber this is great, thanks. Would you mind adding this as an answer? Would be great to see it produces the same results on the same data as user777.

Comment: If you use weighted least squares with the data in my snippet, the parameter estimates satisfy the constraint. There's not too much to show.

Comment: There are problems with such a comparison, Datageek. First, the constraints automatically hold for any reasonable fit to these data. Second, the results shown in this answer are *way* too good: the distributions of the estimates are far too narrow (by one to two orders of magnitude) to be consistent with the actual data. Since I'm unfamiliar with `rstan` I cannot diagnose the problem. I believe, though, that it is unfairly using the *true* parameters `b_hat` in a simulation, so it is unclear to me to what extent it actually is testing the fitting procedure at all.

Comment: @whuber You're right that the results are incredibly precise. But `b_hat` is simply computed from the drawn (and transformed) `sim_x` value, so it is evaluated once for each draw. `b_hat` is *not* read in as if it were data.

Comment: @whuber Does it mean linear regression is not as good as some other solvers in this case? I originally used Excel solver and got really close results as well. I need to solve this problem in R, and preferably with one of the cran libraries that doesn't require installation of additional software.

Comment: No, I think it means something is not quite right about the code in the present solution.  Perhaps I just am not interpreting its output correctly...